# Why do all my urls look like 'content/name-of-page'

Tags: 7, nodes, path-aliases

I just installed [pathauto module](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto). After installing it the path sticks to 'content/' in front of all the url names.
So how to change the default URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to /admin/config/search/path/patterns to configure your content types appropriately. I believe the first one acts as a default if you do not define the other paths for content types.

Comment: Sure enough.  The first time i visited this page I had not cleared my cache and there weren't any patterns displayed.  One `drush cc all` and two refreshes later and everything was resolved. Thanks for the push.